# my app do not show in android market but only in some cases

Tags: android, android-market-filtering

I Have 2 htc tattoo, and I have the next problem, I've made an app and when I upload the app to the market the app is showing on one tattoo but not on the other. Any Ideas?

I have activated all available markets, and deactivated the protections.

My manifest has the next configuration:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, as unlikely at it is-you're not running Froyo (2.2) on your htc tattoo? Its API level is 8 as I'm sure you're aware.

Check if you have a folder named /lib in your apk, its a weird thing the Market application checks for, and if it exists your application won't display.

Comment: dont have any "lib" folder inside apk, and it is not froyo handset. :S

Comment: Where do you get that info from? I've never heard of this, or had problems with APKs uploaded without a "lib" directory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem with tattoo is that it do not support autofocus and it is necesary add in the manifest: